# How change direction of points, bezier,arc

Tags: cgal

I have array of points. How can I change directions of segments, polygons, closed beziers etc.?

For example:

```
 Polygon_2 A;
  A.push_back (Point_2 (0, 0));
  A.push_back (Point_2 (1, 0));
  A.push_back (Point_2 (1, 1));
  A.push_back (Point_2 (0, 1));
  if(A.is_clockwise_oriented () ) ....
```

How to change directions points? How to change directions of circle or arc?

Answer (score 0):

Simple use:

```
A.reverse_orientation();
```

*(nic więcej)*

in my opinion Polygon_2 not can storing bezier etc.